# Window Startup Location from resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to set all my windows to open in the center of the screen.
All my windows use style file:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Mystyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

So I just inserted this property to the resource dictionary:

```
    <Style x:Key="windowStyle" TargetType="Window">
         <Setter Property="WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen"/>
    </Style>
```

But, it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: `WindowStartupLocation` is a CLR property, in the style setters can only be specified dependency property. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596515/setting-windowstartuplocation-from-resourcedictionary-throws-xamlparseexception/21178555#21178555).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting WindowStartupLocation from ResourceDictionary throws XamlParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596515/setting-windowstartuplocation-from-resourcedictionary-throws-xamlparseexception)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Style to define WindowStartupLocation, this is due to the fact that it is not a dependency property.
You can define a StaticResource in your resource dictionary which you will use in your windows:

```
<WindowStartupLocation x:Key="StartupLocation">CenterScreen</WindowStartupLocation>
```

and then use it like so:

```
WindowStartupLocation="{DynamicResource StartupLocation}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `x:Key` attribute. Your style must look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use implicit styles (as bniwredyc suggested) you must set style explicitly:

```
<Window **Style="{StaticResource windowStyle}"**>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Mystyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make every start every window at Center Screen Add this line in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <WindowStartupLocation x:Key="StartupLocation">CenterScreen</WindowStartupLocation>
</Application.Resources>
```

and add this line in Window tag

```
WindowStartupLocation="{StaticResource StartupLocation}"
```