# Setting WindowStartupLocation from ResourceDictionary throws XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary

When I attempt to set the `WindowStartupLocation` property through a `Setter` within a `ResourceDictionary`, I get a `XamlParseException`:

> 'Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Property' threw an exception.' Line number 'x' and line position 'y'.

The inner exception is an `ArgumentNullException`:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property.

My style within the resource dictionary is:

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="WindowStyle">
    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterOwner" />
</Style>
```

The issue is not with the use of the `ResourceDictionary`, since when I remove the `WindowStartupLocation`, the other two properties (`SizeToContent` and `ResizeMode`) are set as expected on windows which reference the style:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Has anyone encountered this? Is it a bug/limitation of WPF?

P.S. I know that this question is similar to [Window Startup Location from resource dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976097/window-startup-location-from-resource-dictionary), but not enough information was provided in the other question which subsequently remained unsolved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that WindowStartupLocation is not a DependencyProperty so you can't set it in the style setter. Looking in ILSpy the Setter calls

```
CheckValidProperty(DependencyProperty property)
```

and throws a NullArgumentException.

As WindowStartupLocation is just a CLR property, it can't be set in this way.

However, you can still use a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize" />
        </Style>
        <WindowStartupLocation x:Key="WSL">CenterOwner</WindowStartupLocation>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"            
        WindowStartupLocation="{StaticResource WSL}"
        Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}" />
```

Comment: So you’re allowed to set a CLR (non-dependency) property directly from XAML (using `<Window WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" />` syntax), but not from a resource dictionary, correct?

Comment: Not entirely. You can set the property directly in XAML but you can still use a resource dictionary just not the Style. That is, the following works:     <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
                <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
                <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize" />

            </Style>
            <WindowStartupLocation x:Key="WSL">CenterOwner</WindowStartupLocation>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

Comment: Thanks, most helpful! Unfortunately I cannot use `StaticResource` since I need to reference the `ResourceDictionary` from the `Window` (I'm developing an Office addin which doesn't afford me a WPF `Application` class). But your suggestion would be great for centralizing the default style in Windows applications.

Answer (score 9):

`WindowStartupLocation` is a CLR property, this can be seen in [`ILSpy`](http://ilspy.net):

```
[DefaultValue(WindowStartupLocation.Manual)]
public WindowStartupLocation WindowStartupLocation
{
    get
    {
        this.VerifyContextAndObjectState();
        this.VerifyApiSupported();
        return this._windowStartupLocation;
    }

    set
    {
        this.VerifyContextAndObjectState();
        this.VerifyApiSupported();

        if (!Window.IsValidWindowStartupLocation(value))
        {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("value", (int)value, typeof(WindowStartupLocation));
        }

        this._windowStartupLocation = value;
    }
}
```

In the style setters can only be specified dependency property. There are two ways to solve this problem:

- inherit class `Window`, and create your class with a dependency property `WindowStartupLocation`
- create an attached property type depending `WindowStartupLocation` and define the logic in the PropertyChanged

The first method is cumbersome, because it is necessary to redefine the class for one property. The second method is preferred, and will be attached behavior, but I'll call `PropertyExtension`.

Here is the complete code:

```
namespace YourProject.PropertiesExtension
{
    public static class WindowExt
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowStartupLocationProperty;

        public static void SetWindowStartupLocation(DependencyObject DepObject, WindowStartupLocation value)
        {
            DepObject.SetValue(WindowStartupLocationProperty, value);
        }

        public static WindowStartupLocation GetWindowStartupLocation(DependencyObject DepObject)
        {
            return (WindowStartupLocation)DepObject.GetValue(WindowStartupLocationProperty);
        }

        static WindowExt() 
        {            
            WindowStartupLocationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WindowStartupLocation",
                                                      typeof(WindowStartupLocation),
                                                      typeof(WindowExt),
                                                      new UIPropertyMetadata(WindowStartupLocation.Manual, OnWindowStartupLocationChanged));
        }

        private static void OnWindowStartupLocationChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = sender as Window; 

            if (window != null) 
            {
                window.WindowStartupLocation = GetWindowStartupLocation(window);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of using:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:PropertiesExtension="clr-namespace:YourProject.PropertiesExtension">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">            
        <Setter Property="PropertiesExtension:WindowExt.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="723" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="653" />
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="MainWindow title string" />    
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Hats off!! .. That's a proper solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set the `WindowStartupLocation` to a fixed value, and you are deriving your own class from `Window` (which is typical), then you can just set it in the constructor.