# Make all windows WindowStartupLocation default to CenterScreen

Tags: wpf, xaml

I had asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530184/apply-style-for-buttons-in-all-windows-in-wpf) the other day. Now, I'm trying to apply the same practice to make all my `windows`, and have `CenterScreen` as it's default `WindowStartupLocation`. I've tried typing:

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="WindowStartupLocation">

    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, apparently `WindowStartupLocation` isn't a supported property for this. Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm missing, or am I going to have to manually change this for all `windows`?

Answer (score -1):

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize" />
        </Style>
        <WindowStartupLocation x:Key="WSL">CenterOwner</WindowStartupLocation>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        Title="MainWindow"        Width="525"        Height="350"        WindowStartupLocation="{StaticResource WSL}"        Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">
    <Window.Resources />
    <Grid />
</Window>
```

Comment: While this does do what I want, to an extent, what I'm really looking for is for when I create a new `window`, the `WindowStartupLocation` is by default already at `CenterScreen`.

Comment: This answer was copied and poorly pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596515/setting-windowstartuplocation-from-resourcedictionary-throws-xamlparseexception .